# Open document from one-drive directly in office365 offline through graph API

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm using the graph API to access the documents in one-drive and I want that the preview URL, generated by the [endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_preview) should open the document directly in office 365 offline, instead of first opening it in online mode and then click on `edit in word`.

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of `/preview` is to open a document in a "viewer", not an editor (thus the name "preview").

If you want to open it in an editor, you can use the [`webUrl`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/driveitem#properties) property of the item. Navigating to this property will open the document in it's associated editor.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Marc, but I didn't get how can I use webURL for opening the document in office app. In the mean while, I was looking into [office uri schemes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/office-uri-schemes). I can use this, but the document in my case is shared among multiple users, for which, I was generating url using `POST /shares/{shareId}/driveItem/preview` endpoint. But the url generated by this API can't be used with uri scheme. Can you suggest any solution for this?

Comment: The `webUrl` property is returned with the `DriveItem` object. You retrieve this using the item's `id`: `GET /me/drive/items/{item-id}`

Comment: yes, I get it but it'll open the document in office web application, but my question is how can I directly open the document is the desktop application.

Comment: There is a `webDavUrl` property that the desktop applications can use. This is a little more fragile however since it would _require_ the desktop app be present. Using `webUrl` ensures it works on any platform (Windows, Mac, even mobile devices).

Comment: Ok, certainly this could help me but I'm not getting `webDevUrl` when I hit request for `drive item`.

Comment: How are you requesting the `DriveItem`?

Comment: ```curl -X GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{item-id} -H 'Authorization: Bearer Token'```

Comment: Hmm, it looks like you need to force `webDavUrl` to be returned by adding it to a `$select` statement. This isn't in the docs but I'm not sure if this represents an error in the docs or a bug in the API. Regardless, something like `/v1.0/me/drive/items/{item-id}?$select=id,name,size,parentReference,webDavUrl` should give you want you're looking for. You will of course want to add/substract to the properties list to match what you want to get returned by the API.

Comment: Hey, I'm bothering you again, but this `webDevUrl` is downloading the document  and then opening it. I mean I can't use it for co-authoring purpose as it is not opening it directly from oneDrive.

Comment: For co-authoring you need to use the `webUrl`. The user can then optionally open it in their desktop client.